# Unable to get the news articles link in google news page using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The below script goes to news page after searching for the text "Liverpool" and then prints all the links to a file and prints them in the console as well.
The problem here is I am unable to get the links to all the news articles in google news page. Except that all other links to the page are getting printed

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String URL = "https://www.google.com";
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(URL);
        WebElement searchBar = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lst-ib']"));
        searchBar.sendKeys("Liverpool");
        WebElement clickSearch = driver.findElement(By.name("btnK"));
        clickSearch.click();
        WebElement newsButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='hdtb-msb-vis']/div[2]/a"));
        newsButton.click();
        java.util.List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println(links.size());
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/Users/lekharaj/Desktop/LFC.txt");
        BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(file);
        for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++){
            String text = links.get(i).getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println("\n"+text);
            b.write(text);
            b.newLine();
            b.flush();
            }
    }
```

Comment: which value return from links.size() ?

Comment: I am getting 104 as output for links.size()

Comment: If you only want to get the news link then use findElements more specific one something like class or Id....

Comment: maybe you can try with By.ClassName('lLrAF')... try it

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for the text **Liverpool** on *Google Home Page*, and then print all the links you can use the following solution :

- Code Block :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");
  WebElement submit_button = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
  submit_button.sendKeys("Liverpool");
  submit_button.submit();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("News"))).click();
  List <WebElement> my_list = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("h3.r.dO0Ag>a")));
  System.out.println("The list of href links are : ");
  for(WebElement element:my_list)
      System.out.println(element.getAttribute("href"));
  ```
- Console Output :

  ```
  The list of href links are : 
  http://www.espn.com/soccer/club/liverpool/364/blog/post/3506156/jurgen-klopp-stability-at-liverpool-the-envy-of-their-premier-league-rivals
  https://www.liverpoolfc.com/news/first-team/302415-liverpool-fc-songs-fans-europe
  http://www.espn.com/soccer/club/liverpool/364/blog/post/3489163/liverpools-andrew-robertson-hoping-to-mimic-predecessor-alan-kennedys-heroics-against-real-madrid
  https://www.liverpoolecho.co.uk/sport/football/transfer-news/christian-pulisic-refuses-comment-reports-14688647
  https://www.liverpoolecho.co.uk/sport/football/football-news/liverpool-legend-terry-mcdermotts-three-14688746
  http://www.skysports.com/football/news/11669/11381416/liverpool-transfer-rumours-gianluigi-donnarumma-daniel-ceballos-jamaal-lascelles-and-james-tarkowski
  http://www.skysports.com/more-sports/ufc/news/29876/11380754/ufc-how-liverpool-built-darren-till
  https://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/transfers/liverpool-transfer-news-jurgen-klopp-shortlist-tarkowski-lascelles-premier-league-epl-a8361576.html
  https://www.belfasttelegraph.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/liverpool/this-real-madrid-star-can-crush-liverpools-champions-league-dream-says-giggs-36932660.html
  http://kwese.espn.com/football/blog/transfer-talk/79/post/3506910/transfer-rater-neymar-to-real-madridjamaal-lascelles-to-liverpool
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following x-path to get only article links.

```
//article/a
```

In code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String URL = "https://www.google.com";
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(URL);
    WebElement searchBar = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lst-ib']"));
    searchBar.sendKeys("Liverpool");
    WebElement clickSearch = driver.findElement(By.name("btnK"));
    clickSearch.click();
    WebElement newsButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='hdtb-msb-vis']/div[2]/a"));
    newsButton.click();
    java.util.List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//article/a"));
    System.out.println(links.size());
    FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/Users/lekharaj/Desktop/LFC.txt");
    BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(file);
    for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++){
        String text = links.get(i).getAttribute("href");
        System.out.println("\n"+text);
        b.write(text);
        b.newLine();
        b.flush();
        }
}
```